# External keyboard Logitech Slim Folio Pro not always allow me to type text on iPadOS 14.2

Tags: keyboard, ipados

Sometimes I am  unable to type text into text field in the apps on iPadOS 14.2 (the same behaviour I encountered before on previous versions of the iPadOS).

Sometimes this also happening for "Spotlight" but this is rarer than for the apps.

I could use function keys in that moment so this is not an issue with connectivity.
This is probable some "feature" of Apple system. How I could avoid this  problem?
I use Logitech Slim Folio Pro (Bluetooth keyboard & cover)

Answer (score 1):

#### **Restart your iPad**

(or sometimes removing the keyboard, turning display on/off, and then reattaching the keyboard works, but less often)

I run into this problem frequently with the Smart Keyboard with the 1st-gen iPad Pro 11". Even though some keys are recognized—such as being able to bring up the Spotlight search with `CMD+Space`—none of the text keys work to be able to type anything in. Restarting is the only guaranteed workaround I've found so far.

For the quickest restart—about ~45s in total—do this in quick sequence:

1. Press Volume Up button
2. Press Volume Down button
3. Hold the Power Button until the iPad shuts down and the Apple logo appears